# Add column to data frame based on long list and values in another column is too slow

Tags: r, list, apply, dplyr

I am adding a new column to a dataframe using apply() and mutate. It works. Unfortunately, it is very slow. I have 24M rows and I am adding column based on values in a long (58 items). It was bearable with smaller list. Not anymore.
Here is my example

```
large_df <-data.frame(A=(1:4),
                   B= c('a','b','c','d'),
                  C= c('e','f','g','h')) 
long_list = c('e','f','g')

large_df =mutate (large_df, new_C = apply(large_df[,2:3], 1, 
                 function(r) any(r %in% long_list)))
```

The new column (new_C) will read True or False. It works but I am looking for a speedy alternative.

Thank you so much.
Serhiy

Bonus Q. I couldn't just select one column with in apply(), needed range. Why?

Comment: Consider using ´data.table´, it is reasonably faster for large data sets. If you want to use ´tidyverse´, mapping over the list might be helpful, but it is rather difficult to understand what are you trying to do. If you add some example data (´dput()´), others may find it easier to help you.

Comment: Adding columns/rows dynamically is generally very slow in R because the complete data is copied in each step, thereby making it an O(n^2) routine. Can you somehow compute the number of columns needed beforehand? In this case you can allocate the entire data.frame and subsequently only need to assign values to the already allocated memory. This reduces the addition of data to O(n) riuntime complexity.

Comment: Thank you knytt.  I have tried 'data.table' package and it sped up many steps. Shaved off 20% here but about 50% manipulating data before hand. Thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try one of these alternatives using `lapply` :

```
large_df$new_c <- Reduce(`|`, lapply(large_df[, 2:3], `%in%`, long_list))
```

or `sapply` :

```
large_df$new_c <- rowSums(sapply(large_df[, 2:3], `%in%`, long_list)) > 0
```

Both of which return :

```
large_df
#  A B C new_c
#1 1 a e  TRUE
#2 2 b f  TRUE
#3 3 c g  TRUE
#4 4 d h FALSE
```

Comment: Thank you Ronak. With knytt suggestion to use data.table and Reduce() lapply() my lapse time  improved 12 fold.